# Obj-c OS X: Populate Items in a Table View

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, tableview

I have cobbled together the following code to populate a Table View and want to be able to populate it from an array. 
Can anyone show me some how?

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
// Insert code here to tear down your application
NSLog(@"a"); }

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
NSRect          scrollFrame = NSMakeRect( 20, 74, 155, 296);
NSScrollView*   scrollView  = [[NSScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollFrame];

[scrollView setBorderType:NSBezelBorder];
NSRect          clipViewBounds  = [[scrollView contentView] bounds];
NSTableView*    tableView       = [[NSTableView alloc] initWithFrame:clipViewBounds];

NSTableColumn*  firstColumn     = [[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier:@""];
[tableView  addTableColumn:firstColumn];
[tableView setHeaderView:nil];
[tableView setDataSource:self];
[tableView setRowHeight:40.0];
[scrollView setDocumentView:tableView];
[[[self window] contentView] addSubview:scrollView];

}

 - (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView
{
   return 5;
}

- (id) tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
 {

NSString* cellValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %ld", [aTableColumn identifier], (long)rowIndex];

return cellValue;
 }
```

Comment: do you need to add functionality to the tableView or just texts to the cells? and are you using nib(storyboard) or xib?

Comment: Using XIB file. The only functionality I need to add is the ability to set the background color of each cell.

Comment: Storyboards allow you to fully configure static table views and their cells.

Comment: I've updated my question with some code I was able to cobble together. Any ideas as to how I might be able to use an array instead of printing 1, 2 , 3, 4, 5 ?

Comment: You can store  the values in an array and supply those in data source. like NSArray *a = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",nil]; - (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView
{
   return [a count];
}- (id) tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
 {

NSString* cellValue = [a objectAtIndex:rowIndex];

return cellValue;
 }

Answer (score -1):

First i recommend not using Static cells. In order to successfully create a tableView with static cells you need to keep a reference to each cell and add the data to it, this can create a big mess in you code.

If you only want to add the ability  to change the background color of your cell, i recommend using prototype cells (that is your cells have common elements in them).

But if you insist on using static cells you need to keep a reference to all the cells in the tableView